# Border radius not work with Button

Tags: button, react-native, react-native-ios, touchableopacity

I want to create a border radius button with touchableOpacity.

I tried this style :

```
whiteButton : {
    borderWidth:1,
    overflow : "hidden",
    marginTop: "3%",
    backgroundColor:"white",
    width:"80%",height:"6%",
    borderRadius : 20,
    borderColor:"white",
    marginBottom:10
}
```

But the button looks like this :

[image: Only the white part]

And if I remove overflow : "hidden", it looks like this :

[image]

Do you have an idea ?

EDIT :

After setting backgroundColor of the text to transparent, I have the same result as overflow : "hidden" but with the text just below It's like my text is out of the touchableopacity

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From react [native material design](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design.github.io/blob/master/components/button.md),

> The button component renders a touchable button with consumes the **full
>   width of it's parent container**.

Consumes full width of it's parent, which means add a padding onto `TouchableOpacity` works. (which is `whiteButton` of your style)

[image]

For me `padding: 2` is sufficient to `borderRadius: 10`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your text inside the button stretches to the button's boundaries, hence border radius won't apply. You need to increase your button size or decrease the text size so that there is space at the boundaries to allow border radius to be implemented. Also, you need to make sure that text is centered(use `justifyContent` and `alignItems`) inside the button so that it doesn't touches button's boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was in my code.
I've not seen but I added a view and touchableopacity was wrapped in my view.

Before :

```
<View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.sendLoginData()}} style={styles.whiteButton}>
         <Text style={{textAlign:"center", fontSize:25, color:"#3b88c3", backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}}>S'IDENTIFIER</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Afer :

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.sendLoginData()}} style={styles.whiteButton}>
     <Text style={{textAlign:"center", fontSize:25, color:"#3b88c3", backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}}>S'IDENTIFIER</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```